# Hooking up iMac, DSL modem, router, VoIP box and ROKU

Tags: macos, router, modem, voip, imac

I want to hoop up iMac, DSL modem, router, VoIP box and ROKU.

How do I begin?  I've read to go from wall to modem to router to VOIP, then I guess I'd just get another cable to hook the ROKU to the router?

Hardware: iMac, Clear DSL modem and VOIP box, Apple Airport Extreme, ROKU XD. Currently, the iMac, modem and VOIP are hooked up and working great, but how do I introduce the router and ROKU to the mix?

Comment: Did you not receive a manual or quick-start guide with your router or other hardware?

Comment: Sure I rec'd all the manuals/guides but none of them include the VOIP adapter.

Comment: what VOIP adaptor?

Comment: Just plug your VOIP adaptor into your router/switch, same as you would any other network device.

Answer (score 1):

If its anything like the cisco VIOP adaptor i'm used to, it acts as a router as well - if you plug a system into the second ethernet port, it'll give you a 192.168.x.x ip address. If it dosen't act as a router, you will want to run your router proper on a seperate subnet - else you can either do that, or turn off DHCP on the router and let the VOIP adaptor handle routing.

You could also connect the VOIP adaptor to the router, but least with mine, they recommended you not do so.

Or in pictures, this layout should work.

```
      +-------------------+
      | Router            |
      |-------------------|
      | (turn off DHCP    |
      |  or use different |+---------> VOIP Adaptor +-----------> Modem
      |  subnet if VOIP   |
      |  Adaptor has a    |
      |  built in router  |
      +-------------------+
```